# mouse enters, decrease the size of the image by 5% each second

Tags: javascript

I put an image in a div. When I move the mouse into the div, the image should decrease by 5% every second. I've done this script but nothing happens.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  const element = document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0];
  const div = element.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  var urlImg = "https://www.coding-academy.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/CODING_LOGO_CMJN.png";

  var imagejavascript = document.createElement("img");
  imagejavascript.src = urlImg;
  imagejavascript.style.width = "100%";
  imagejavascript.style.height = "100%";
  div.appendChild(imagejavascript);

  const img = div.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
  var isOnDiv = false;
  var currentHeight = 100;

  div.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    if (isOnDiv) return;
    isOnDiv = true;

    var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
      currentHeight -= 5;
      img.style.height = currentHeight + "%";

      if (currentHeight <= 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        setTimeout(function() {
          isOnDiv = false;
          currentHeight = 100;
          img.style.height = "100%";
        }, 1000);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });

  div.addEventListener("click", function() {
    div.removeChild(img);
  });
});
```

```html
<footer>
  <div></div>
</footer>
```

I'm trying to find a way to reduce the image size by 5% every second I enter the mouse in the div.

Comment: If you change the "%" with "vw" your code works, but the answer that you select it's better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues here:

- You're setting both `height` and `width` of the `img` to `100%`. A change to a single one of them will have no effect. You need to set one of the values and have the image scale dynamically as you change that property's value.
- Don't use a variable (ie. `isOnDiv`) to maintain hover state. Use separate `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event handlers to start and end the interval, respectively.

Here's a working example with the above changes made:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  const element = document.querySelector("footer");
  const div = element.querySelector("div");
  
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "https://www.coding-academy.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/CODING_LOGO_CMJN.png";
  img.style.width = "100%";
  div.appendChild(img);

  let currentWidth = 100;
  let intervalId;
  
  const setImgSize = value => img.style.width = value + "%";

  div.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
      currentWidth -= 5;
      setImgSize(currentWidth);
      
      if (currentWidth <= 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
  
  div.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    currentWidth = 100;
    setImgSize(currentWidth);
  }); 

  div.addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    div.removeChild(img);
  });
});
```

```html
<footer>
  <div></div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting height by percentage only works when the parent element has a fixed height. In your case, there is no styling on the parent `div`, so the width and height styling of your image does not work.

One way to fix is to first render the image in your `div`, and then set the height and width of your `div` to its current calculated dimensions. You can put the following lines of code after inserting the image to the div:

```js
// After div.appendChild(imagejavascript);

div.style.height = `${div.clientHeight}px`;
div.style.width = `${div.clientWidth}px`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was almost correct. Here is another way by not changing much your code. Your attempt to use the flag isOnDiv is not correct you should use on mouseleave event.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    const element = document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0];
    const div = element.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    var urlImg = "https://www.coding-academy.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/CODING_LOGO_CMJN.png";
    let intervalId
    var imagejavascript = document.createElement("img");
    imagejavascript.src = urlImg;
    imagejavascript.style.width = "100%";
    div.appendChild(imagejavascript);
  
    const img = div.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
    let currentHeight = 100;
  
    div.addEventListener("mouseenter", () =>{
        intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        currentHeight -= 5;
        img.style.width = currentHeight+"%";
        console.log ({currentHeight})
        if (currentHeight <= 0) {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          setTimeout(function() {
            currentHeight = 100;
            img.style.height = "100%";
          }, 1000);
        }
      }, 1000);
    });

    div.addEventListener("mouseleave", ()=>{
        clearInterval(intervalId)
        img.style.width = "100%";
        currentHeight = 100;
    })
  
    div.addEventListener("click", function() {
      div.removeChild(img);
    });
  });
```